# How to notify a Cab or Taxi Operator using GPS

Tags: ios, gps, location

Using GPS, how can I notify a cab operator in the area if I wanted to be fetched? I've seen a lot of apps regarding finding a taxi and fetch you wherever you are, example http://www.taxifinder.com/ .

I'm wondering what's the idea behind it?
Does the cab operator need to have a server where I can access it and tell them I need a taxi?
I really don't know how to do it, can someone enlighten me. Steps / list on how it should be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the scalability of it but here is a try:

1. A webserver that can process the request from the frontend and processes it. A simple case scenario would be that it receives the requestor's information including GPS coordinates. It would then check for drivers in the vicinity that are registered to the webserver and dispatch the push notifications to them.
2. A push notification system to push the notification to the cab driver/s. Check out [Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) although I believe there are no options for filtering the users in this case.
3. A web/native application that communicated with the server.

ps. The Taxi driver/s will have to have their devices registered for the push notification. On a second thought, the Taxi driver[s]' location access would be required as well so as to filter the drivers that would receive the dispatch request. Then maybe add a functionality where if one driver 'accepts' the dispatch, the user is notified and the other drivers cannot accept it any more.

Comment: So, I need to access a webserver of the cab operator? Correct me if I'm wrong, So the sequence would be... I notify a cab operator by accessing their web server, giving them my coordinates.. Then, the cab operator will look  which among their cabs are nearest to my area... Then, when found, they notify the cab driver (with the device) to tell them that someone's calling for a cab.

Is this correct? :)

Comment: Yes, but just to be clear, a 'human' cab operator per say would not be required. The cab operator, if you will, is the webserver.

Comment: Sir, is it possible to access such webservice outside the country? Though, this sounds funny, Let's say, the cab operator is in US, I'm developing the app here in our country (which is not US) but the app will be deployed in US.. :)

Comment: @JennEve, it is possible to do so. While the scale is off the chart, think about a Facebook app for the iPhone. If you have your notification setting on for Facebook and a friend from say - Nepal posts something on your wall, you still get the notification. I am sorry for the strange analogy but the short answer is yes.

Comment: I don't mean the notification, but the service that I will be calling, is there such API/service that everyone can call to give us the info regarding the cabs we needed? 
Thank you so much for your giving time to answer my questions, Sir.

Comment: I haven't looked into much detail but I just googled from Taxi Location API and this is the link that I found. [TaxiFareFinder](http://www.taxifarefinder.com/api.php) I think it currently only supports Fare comparisons but I am not sure. You might want to check it out.

Comment: You are welcome and here is one more. [Catch-A-Cab](http://www.programmableweb.com/api/catch-a-cab). This is more of an open source api that is not a full service yet.